# Ansible best practices - how to use role/files from files directory?

Tags: ansible

According to [Best Practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html) I keep my script files in roles/X/files structure. So I have:

- roles/X/files/

  - script.sh
  - library.sh
  - library2.sh

In **roles/X/tasks/main.yml** I invoke the script:

`- name: Do something
  script: script.sh --options`

But there is sourcing of a library in the script. I wondered that only script.sh file was copied to **remote_tmp**/ansible-tmp-xxx/script.sh.
For each task, a file is copied to another directory (another temp directory).

Is it normal behavior? I want avoid copying files manually.

`$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.0.0
  ...
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)]`

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

**roles/X/files/test_lib.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LIB="$HOME/.ansible/tmp/lib"
if [[ -f "$LIB/library.sh" ]]; then
    source "$LIB/library.sh"
    do_it
else
    echo "ERROR library.sh not found"
fi
```

**roles/x/files/lib/library.sh**

```
do_it() {
    echo "I'm the library"
}
```

**roles/X/tasks/main.yml**

```
---
- name: Creates directory
  file:
    path: $HOME/.ansible/tmp
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
- name: Check if required files exist
  stat:
    path: $HOME/.ansible/tmp/lib/library.sh
  register: stat_lib_directory
- name: Copy library
  # this copies lib from $HOME!!!
  #command: cp -r lib/. $HOME/.ansible/tmp/
  copy:
    src: lib
    dest: $HOME/.ansible/tmp
    directory_mode: 0755
    mode: 0644
  when: stat_lib_directory.stat.exists == False
- name: Run the script on remote host
  script: test_lib.sh
  register: out
- debug: var=out.stdout_lines
- name: Cleaning
  file:
    path: $HOME/.ansible/tmp/lib
    state: absent
```

And it finally works:

```
$ ansible-playbook copy-dir.yml

PLAY [host] ****************************************************************************

TASK [copy-dir : Creates directory] ****************************************************
ok: [host]

TASK [copy-dir : Check if required files exist] ****************************************
ok: [host]

TASK [copy-dir : Copy library] *********************************************************
changed: [host]

TASK [copy-dir : Run the script on remote host] ****************************************
changed: [host]

TASK [copy-dir : debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [host] => {
    "out.stdout_lines": [
        "\u001b[?1034hI'm the library"
    ]
}

TASK [copy-dir : Cleaning] *************************************************************
changed: [host]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
host                       : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ansible.builtin.copy and let ansible handles it for you?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html

Although if I have a shell script long enough that requires libraries I'd probably rewrite that in Python and even turn that into a Ansible module!
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html

Have fun!